# Java Inserting space after a certain character has been found in a string

Tags: java, string

How would I go about adding a space **AFTER** a specific character in the string has been found? Example.... I'd want to add a space after the "#" character in that string. I'm also wondering how I could get the position I was currently at if there were multiple "#" in my string.

(2/9) B (4/3) / #
(1/2) (-1/3) (3/2) (-1/11) * * - 
  (1/2) + (2/2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
str = str.replace("#", "# ");
```

Comment: Okay and now I'll edit my question and add an additional question below it. It has to do with this idea and concept.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question; rather than tacking stuff on to a question that already has a perfectly good answer that deserves to be accepted.